# No application found to handle ...(Launchy::ApplicationNotFoundError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed capybara-screenshot gem to save the screenshot and in cucumber step definition i called screenshot_and_open_image but i got error that says:

> No application found to handle
>   'application_path/public/tmp/screenshot_2014-06-18-11-07-39.063.png'
>   (Launchy::ApplicationNotFoundError)

Can anybody assist me?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `Capybara::Screenshot.screenshot_and_open_image`. And if you have a **test javascript** please specify `js: true` for **him**.

`it "my test", js: true do
   blablabla
 end`

Comment: I don't think this helps, as the OP is already using screenshot_and_open_image

Comment: then you need to specify js: true in the test unless specified